# Real time Sonic Visualizer, to analize current played audios internly in the computer

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, ubuntu-studio, monitoring

I need to be able to see a real time spectogram of all audios been reproduced at that moment whatever where in the computer ( youtube, facebook, mediaplayers, microfone).

i dont know if sonic visualizer have this function ... I dont know other good spectogram analizers tho.

Any tips ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running Ubuntu Studio 18.04, you need to add the [Ubuntu Studio Backports PPA](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/BackportsPPA) to get some updated software.

This will include the updated Calf Studio Gear plugins which include an analyzer. However, they require Jack in order to run. Once you have the PPA enabled and your system upgraded, also install Carla (`sudo apt install carla`) as this will let you put the analyzer in your audio chain the way you need it.

Next, run [Ubuntu Studio Controls](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UbuntuStudioControls) and configure your audio, and start Jack. Open Carla, and add the Calf Analyzer plugin. From the Patchbay tab, this can then be patched to your microphones or other applications. If it's not a Jack-aware application, such as a web browser, patch the audio output of PulseOut to the input of the analyzer. If you wish to listen to the audio, either patch the output of the analyzer to your system output or patch PulseOut directly to your system output.

Double-clicking the analyzer in the patchbay or clicking the GUI button on the plugin in the rack tab will open the analyzer's window.